# Calculate creation number grouped by category in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres and did not find a efficient solution to my problem.
I have a table with basically an Id and a category. Now I want to calculate the the creation number of each id grouped by the category.

For example I have this table:

```
+----+----------+
| id | category |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        2 |
|  4 |        2 |
+----+----------+
```

and the end result after the query should look like:

```
+----+----------+-----------------+
| id | category | creation_number |
+----+----------+-----------------+
|  1 |        1 |               1 |
|  2 |        1 |               2 |
|  3 |        2 |               1 |
|  4 |        2 |               2 |
+----+----------+-----------------+
```

id:1 was created first in category 1; id:2 was created second in category 1 etc

My current query looks like this but is extremely slow:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test t2
        WHERE t2.category = t1.category AND
            t2.id <= t1.id
    ) creation_number
FROM test t1
```

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions!:

```
select t1.*,
       row_number() over (partition by category order by id) as creation_number
from test t1;
```

Not only is this more concise, but it should be much faster as well on any but the smallest tables.